# C# static class, constructor takes parameters

Tags: c#, constructor, static

I'm creating a class that should not allow instances to be created. However the constructor that takes a width (double), height (double), x (double), and y (double).
I was thinking about doing a static class since it cannot have an instance but when it comes the the constructor I am having issues.

Comment: What you are describing is more like a method than a class.

Comment: Can you please go into a bit more detail for your question? It seems like you have some incorrect definitions.

Comment: What is your end goal?  Are you trying to perform a calculation and return a value? Or are you trying to return an object that has some properties?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of the exact problem you are trying to solve, but you cannot have an instance constructor for a static class.  Take a look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx

Perhaps you want to create an abstract class?

Comment: abstract I didn't even think of that. Thanks its my four week programming and I'm still getting the hang of it.

Comment: @BrandonO'Dell I warmly suggest this article to you: Static Constructors https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx

Comment: @MihaiCaracostea - Yes, I understand you can have a static constructor on a normal class. But you can't have a constructor on a static class.

Comment: @BrandonO'Dell Actually, you can! You should read the article you posted in your answer! Mostly the part that says "As is the case with all class types, the type information for a static class is loaded by the .NET Framework common language runtime (CLR) when the program that references the class is loaded. The program cannot specify exactly when the class is loaded. However, it is guaranteed to be loaded and to have its fields initialized and its static constructor called before the class is referenced for the first time in your program."

Comment: @MihaiCaracostea - My apologies I didn't specify 'instance' constructor. I figured it was a bit implied, which, by the original question being asked, is what the author was trying to do. He was trying to call a constructor with parameters.  That is not something you can do on a static class or static constructor.

Comment: @MihaiCaracostea - And yes, there is that too ;)  Hard to give an exact solution when you don't know the exact problem. I was just trying to give pointers to help him along in the right direction....wherever that may be.